# I got a error,when i start my computer

Tags: mount

i am getting this type of problem,when i open my computer(continue to wait or press s to skip mounting or m for manual recovery)

please help me regarding this

Comment: Can you post the output of `[sudo] blkid` and `[sudo] cat /etc/fstab` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From observing your short question, I'm led to believe one of your UUID's are incorrect in /etc/fstab

What you could do as Step 1, is to type:

```
    sudo blkid
```

then for Step 2 type:

```
    sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and compare the UUID's of all listed devices between the blkid output and your fstab file.

If any information does not match, edit fstab as root and correct the discrepancies.

Comment: what will be the next step.......i followed both step but i didn't understand last statement whatever you written that, i am new in ubuntu and not familiar with terminal.......thank you

Comment: @user299160, let me reiterate my last sentence. Compare the output of `sudo blkid`, and the output of `sudo nano /etc/fstab` (you could also do `sudo cat /etc/fstab`. Do your device UUID's match? If not, edit `/etc/fstab` so they do match.

Comment: i am getting this type of problem,when i start my computer then i got a message............the disk drive for /(Drive Name) is not ready yet or not present......continue to wait or press s to skip mounting or m for manual recovery....is this any problem in hard disk....please help me out thank you

Comment: @user299160 please post your output of blkid and /etc/fstab

Comment: when i followed blkid....out put is...../dev/sda1: UUID="dd145fb1-6162-461e-a557-0fbf6b04dc9d" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Software" UUID="af3da236-a452-484c-a2e1-cc7d3e5b5460" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Amusement" UUID="8d6d7a75-dc31-4c13-b144-efb9215e5171" TYPE="ext4"

Comment: @user299160 try `sudo cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: /etc/fstab....i got...bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied

Comment: @user299160, do you have root access? You shoud be able to access your fstab file using `sudo`. Type `ls -l /etc/fstab` and post output.

Comment: this is the output...  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 935 Jun 30 16:16 /etc/fstab

Comment: I'd guess you forgot the `cat` in `sudo cat /etc/fstab`. Please try again.